# Remove firebase data

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I'm developing a little chat using `Firebase`. My intention was to login to my application and save the user in the database and when you logoff  delete this user.

Currently can only save the user's time to go, time to delete simply nothing happens, no error happens also, it just is not deleted.

**Factory:**

```
angular.module("UnionTi").factory('User', function($firebaseArray,$firebaseObject) {
  var ref = new Firebase(URL);
  var users = $firebaseArray(ref.child('users'));

  var User = {
    all: users,
    create: function (user) {
      return users.$add(user);
    },
    get: function (userId) {
      return $firebaseObject(ref.child('users').child(userId));
    },
    delete: function (user) {
      console.log("usuario: "+user.codigo)
      return users.$remove(user);
    }
  };

  return User;

});
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module("UnionTi").controller("homeCtrl", function($scope, $state, $location, userAuthAPI, User){

  var init = function(){
    $scope.usuarioLogado = userAuthAPI.getUserAuth();
    /**Save user in firebase*/
    User.create($scope.usuarioLogado);
  }

  $scope.logoff = function(){
    $scope.usuarioLogado = userAuthAPI.getUserAuth();
    /**Delete user in firebase*/
    User.delete($scope.usuarioLogado)
    userAuthAPI.logout();
    $state.go('login', {}, {reload: true});
  }

  init();
})
```

How do I delete these records?

[image]

Here is my `$scope.usuarioLogado`:

[image]

Comment: Is `$scope.usuarioLogado` definitely a Firebase reference?

Comment: I think not. `$scope.usuarioLogado` is an object, the same that I created when I login.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-angular/Gl-OWZWS-Ks